# ASP.NET Boilerplate 3.0 Template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-boilerplate

First, thanks for the opportunity,

I noticed that the latest template using ABP 3.0 and aspnetcore 2.0 doesn't come with social logins implementations. Also I cannot register user in UI anymore. I would like to know why they were gone.

Will these features come back in future versions?  I'm afraid to use the codes from previous versions and crash with the new aspnetcore 2.0.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

User Registration is available. There is a register link in the login page: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template#login-page

However you should switch to a tenant for that. Host side does not has register functionality by design.

We removed social logins since the implementation had some problems and we didn't want to provide support for it and wanted to keep startup template simple. It's pretty standard, you can implement yourself by following Microsoft's documents.

Comment: Thanks Very Much, Hikalkan